# Set value with backslash to input in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some input

```
<input id = 'some_id' type='text'/>
```

I want to set value with backslash, for example:

```
$('#some_id').val('someval \')
```

and I'm getting error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

How can I show string value with **backslash** in input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the `\` character like this: `$('#some_id').val('someval \\')`

```js
$('#some_id').val('someval \\')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id = 'some_id' type='text'/>
```

Comment: how can I do it dynamically ? when I'm getting some string variable and I don't know how it looks like ?

Comment: @godot did you ask a separate question for this? or did you vote to reopen the original one? I'm asking because I think it would be good to do that in order to see it in context with this new requirement. Let me know...

Comment: you think that I should ask new question about it?

Comment: @godot I think so, because it would be good to see it as you describe it now, besides it would be too difficult to answer in a comment and if I update the answer it won't help future readers because the original post states a different thing (it doesn't talk about the dynamic part). Drop a link here with the new question.

Comment: okay, I accepted your answer.